# prometheus node_exporter system requirements

Tags: linux, devops, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-node-exporter

I have been trying to find a solid resource online but in vain. All sites explain that node exporter was made to collect metrics but I could not find a valid source that site what are the exact(or approx.) resource requirements for the prometheus node exporter. I.e: cpu, ram, storage. Can anyone state them or point to a resource where that information can be found? Any relevant information would help

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about the requirements of the Node Exporter process? They are really low. The "htop" command in an 8 CPUs and 31 GB machine shows:

```
CPU% = 0.0
MEM% = 0.0
```

The node_exporter executable (Linux 64) has just 19MB.

Comment: Yes my question is about resource requirements, trying to find the official recommendations. I have a vps with 1 vcpu and 500mb ram, its really small but node_exporter's footprint seems to be small too and should be working fine since the workload of the server itself is really small as well but the average load spikes up often and I suspect the minimum cpu requirement to be 2x, 1 for the actual workload of the instance and 1 for the node exporter. Its consuming 50 to 60%+ of the server's cpu and the average load is about 4-6 with nothing else to blame on the system.